# Magento viewcart images is pulling in the “default” image thumbnail

Tags: magento

Every product is pulling in the **default** thumbnail image. If I pick different product color with different image, in view cart it is pulling default thumbnail image.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to help.Can you please provide some screenshots and bit more explanation would be great so that other can understand what exactly is your problem.

Comment: If i add to cart 3 same shirts but different color white black and blue and go to view cart  all 3 shirts had same thumbnail image with white shirt

Comment: Have you created the configurable product? How are you managing the colors?

Comment: I have created configurable product. In configurable product  thumbail  selected image is apears in view cart no matter which color i pick. i found out that if i add thumbnail image in simple product for all sizes and colors work good. how should i set configurable product to avoid adding images in every simple product?

Comment: You cannot do so it guess.Either you have to add image to all simple product or you have to use color swatch(this is the extension).

Comment: I use cjm PRESELECT COLORS PLUS SWATCHES - 3.5.4 but i dont see any option to do this without simple image thumbnail. I have all images in configurable product and  selected base image for black and more view image for on always visible and simple product visibility on catalog,search but if dont have thumbnail in simle product in view cart appears selected thumbnail from configurable product for all colors

Answer (score 0):

Check your product in backend have you selected thumb image in product edit form go to admin panel -> catalog -> manage products-> select one product -> images. if not then select thumb image. or check in app/design/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml you will find

$this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(75);

this you need to change to get image instead of thumbnail.